# Relative references to images inside a webview

Tags: android, android-webview, relative-path

I have hundreds of HTML files in my `assets/content1/htmls/` folder. Image sources referred to inside the HTML files are in the folder `assets/content1/images/`. In the HTML files, relative paths to the images are used (e.g. `<img src="../images/1274.jpg" width="547" height="290" border="0"/>`). But the images don't show up in the HTML files.

After researching other SO posts, I tried setting the `BaseUrl` to `file:///android_asset/content1/` and replacing all the `src="../images/"` with `src="images/` in the [`loadDataWithBaseUrl` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Even then, the images did not show up. Can anyone tell me why this is not working? How should relative URLs should be used in webview?

Comment: This may be a long shot, or perhaps something you've already tried by would it help if you put the /images folder within the /htmls folder and have image sources point to <img src="/images/1274.jpg" /> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put your images on content1 folder then write like this in html file

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/content1/1.jpg" alt="" title="";"/>
```

if it is in images folder then

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/images/1274.jpg" alt="" title="";"/>
```

and it is working coz i have tried out this.

Comment: This works.. But my question was why it is not working even though I use the BaseUrl..